# Strange ordering of ActiveRecord object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to get the records to order by `:id` in the view. I have records ordered by `:id` in the controller, like so

```rb
@bands = Band.where(available: true).order(:id)
```

Everything appears normal when the app starts, but as records are updated, the ordering behaviour goes wonky. Most often, recently edited records move to the very end, but not always. This shouldn't happen since the records are ordered by `:id` which shouldn't be changing

For context, in the view is something like

```rb
<% @bands.each do |b| %>
<%= b.name %>
<% end %>
```

Also note, in the rails console, both of these return the ***correctly*** ordered results (which makes this problem even stranger):

```rb
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("SELECT * FROM bands WHERE available = 'true' ORDER BY id")
```

and

```
Band.where(available: true).order(:id)
```

Also note, when I load the `index` view, and observe the rails server, I can see that the results are **not** in the correct order.

I can also see the sql query that has been executed, and it ignores the `order` part, it simply doesn't have any mention of order in the query

Comment: So first, just to be sure, stop your rails server (and stop/kill any `spring` process), and restart it.  Assuming that doesn't fix the problem - please show more code, copy/paste the full index action, plus the logs showing the SQL query being run, also does your `Band` model have any `default_scope`?

Comment: Are you sure that the `@bands` you're using came from `@bands = Band.where(available: true).order(:id)`?

Comment: @muistooshort you were right. I was editing an instance variable (of the same name) in a different controller action

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I don't think it is possible.
But, try this:

```
@bands = Band.where(available: true).order(:id).to_a
```

Comment: Hey Fred, don't ask questions as answers.  Better to post questions as comments on the original question.

Comment: Thanks for the help. It turns out I was editing the right variable but in the wrong action.

Comment: @smathy To be fair, Fred only had 46 rep at the time and you don't get the [comment everywhere](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) privilege until 50.

Comment: @mu yep, wasn't scolding, just pointing out an important distinction.  I actually think his edit was a big improvement (although, obviously, not the correct answer).

Comment: I suggest writing unit tests/specs. And test logic. It always helps to avoid similar situations with the wrong place of code changes.

Comment: Thank you guys. @muistooshort and smathy. And in my opinion, the query with order by primary key( can't be changed in most case)  is always stable. so I shouldn't answer like that.